# qemu-system-aarch64: -device ramfb: 'ramfb' is not a valid device model name

Tags: arm, ubuntu-18.04, virtualization, qemu

I'm using `ubuntu 18.04 for arm64` running on `jetson nano`. I would like to emulate `windows 10 arm` edition using `qemu and kvm`. this is the command line that I have issued :

```
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/seabios/1.14.0-2/+build/20382536/+files/seabios_1.14.0-2_all.deb

dpkg -i seabios_1.14.0-2_all.deb

root@ziomario-desktop:# qemu-system-aarch64 -accel tcg -M virt,virtualization=true -smp 2 -m 2048 -device qemu-xhci -device usb-kbd -device usb-tablet -drive file=/root/Scrivania/Work/win10arm/win10arm.qcow2,if=virtio -drive file="$isoname",media=cdrom,if=none,id=cdrom -device usb-storage,drive=cdrom -drive file="$virtio",media=cdrom,if=none,id=drivers -device usb-storage,drive=drivers -bios /usr/share/qemu-efi-aarch64/QEMU_EFI.fd -vga none -device ramfb

qemu-system-aarch64: -device ramfb: 'ramfb' is not a valid device model name
```

(im using the prebuilt `qemu-system-aarch64 + QEMU_EFI.fd on ubuntu 18.04`. nothing has been built from source,here. What's the problem ?

NB :

I have installed the package `dpkg -i seabios_1.14.0-2_all.deb` because,as @Christian Ehrhardt explained to me,there was a typo in the packaging, due to that this file was missing. It has been fixed in `1.14.0-2` and since it was missing before it is not a bug/degradation that will be fixed in older releases before, but instead it is a new feature only added at this version and later. Seabios has no other dependencies at all. Due to that - as a workaround - you can just download&install the new version onto any Ubuntu release.

Unfortunately after having applied this "patch",it didn't work anyway due to the error that you see above : `"qemu-system-aarch64: -device ramfb: 'ramfb' is not a valid device model name"`. How to fix that ? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say exactly which QEMU version you're using (ie the output of qemu-system-aarch64 --version), but if you're using the stock distro QEMU binary from Ubuntu 18.04 then it is almost certainly simply too old: the ramfb device was introduced in a newer version of QEMU. Try with a more modern QEMU version.

Comment: exactly. I've upgraded all the relevant virtualization packages of ubuntu 18.04 to ubuntu 20.04 and the error is gone.